# Total of two numbers ONLY with bitwise operators?

Tags: python, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

My question is about, how i add two numbers without using bools, if-else conditionals or logical operators?

I have been trying to make a code that adds two numbers in Python, but only using bitwise operators; in other words, without loops, if-else and arithmetic operators.

I have also been looking in this page and other programming sites, but all solutions to this problem have while loops or if-else conditions. I had found a supposed solution, it 
was supposed that it did it recursively, but it generated a recursion error: the maximum depth of recursion exceeds. Because it has not a base case

Now I am asking my self, if it is possible to do that. Then the another question is, It's possible? and if it is, how can I do it?

Here is my failed code:

```
x=7
y=2
def Sum(x, y):
    suma=x^y
    carry=(x&y)<<1
    return Sum(suma, carry)
print(Sum(x, y))
```

Comment: Must it support arbitrary size inputs?

Comment: Yes, those that support memory

Comment: If you're allowing yourself to use recursion and logical operators, you can abuse short-circuit `and`/`or` to branch for the base case, but it's more of an uninteresting flaw in the problem spec than actually performing addition with bitwise operators.

Comment: What do you mean by "those that support memory"?

Comment: Sorry, I'm wrong, the code must admit entries no bigger than 10 ^ 5

Comment: Actually, are you allowing logical operators? Your question contradicts itself. First you say "without using bools, if-else conditionals or logical operators", and then you say "only using bitwise and logical operators".

Comment: Sorry again, you're absolutely right, the code should do it only with bitwise operators, I'll correct that

Comment: Your code is broken because there is no case in which the function does not call itself - recursion absolutely requires a base case!  One possible base case here would be that `carry` is zero, in which case you just return `suma`.

Comment: Yes, you're right, that is the deal, to do that i have to do a if-else condition, and i can't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say in the comments that the inputs must be no greater than 10^5. In that case, a finite number of carry propagation steps will suffice to eliminate the carry term and produce a final sum:

```
def binop_add(x, y):
    sum, carry = x, y
    sum, carry = (sum ^ carry), (sum & carry) << 1 # 1
    sum, carry = (sum ^ carry), (sum & carry) << 1 # 2
    sum, carry = (sum ^ carry), (sum & carry) << 1 # 3
    sum, carry = (sum ^ carry), (sum & carry) << 1 # 4
    sum, carry = (sum ^ carry), (sum & carry) << 1 # 5
    sum, carry = (sum ^ carry), (sum & carry) << 1 # 6
    sum, carry = (sum ^ carry), (sum & carry) << 1 # 7
    sum, carry = (sum ^ carry), (sum & carry) << 1 # 8
    sum, carry = (sum ^ carry), (sum & carry) << 1 # 9
    sum, carry = (sum ^ carry), (sum & carry) << 1 # 10
    sum, carry = (sum ^ carry), (sum & carry) << 1 # 11
    sum, carry = (sum ^ carry), (sum & carry) << 1 # 12
    sum, carry = (sum ^ carry), (sum & carry) << 1 # 13
    sum, carry = (sum ^ carry), (sum & carry) << 1 # 14
    sum, carry = (sum ^ carry), (sum & carry) << 1 # 15
    # assert carry == 0
    return sum
```

Each round of `sum, carry = (sum ^ carry), (sum & carry) << 1` preserves the invariant that `sum + carry == x + y`. After each round, `carry` must end in at least one more 0 bit.

After 15 rounds, `carry` must end in at least 15 zero bits. For `carry` to be nonzero at this point, `carry` would have to be at least `1 << 15`, which is 32768, higher than is possible. At this point, `carry` must be 0, so `sum + carry == sum == x + y`, and we return `sum`.